# The rank of a block matrix as a function of the rank of its submatrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, block-matrices

I would like to post this problem here in this forum.
Having the following block matrix:

\begin{equation}
M=\begin{bmatrix}
S_1 &C\\
C^T &S_2\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

I would like to find the function $f$ that holds $\operatorname{rank}(M)=f( S_1, S_2,C)$
$S_1$ and $S_2$ are covariance matrices $\implies$ symmetric and positive semi-definite.
$C$ is the cross covariance that may be positive semi-definite.

Can you help me?

I sincerely thank you! :)

All the best

GoodSpirit

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** This is impossible. The rank of $M$ is not uniquely determined by the ranks of its subblocks. For example, consider
$$
M=\left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
2&1&0&0\\
1&1&0&\varepsilon\\
\hline
0&0&2&1\\
0&\varepsilon&1&1\\
\end{array}\right].
$$
where $0<\varepsilon\le 1/2$. Then $M,S_1,S_2,C$ are positive semidefinite, $\operatorname{rank}(S_1)=\operatorname{rank}(S_2)=2$ and $\operatorname{rank}(C)=1$, but $\operatorname{rank}(M)=4$ when $\varepsilon<1/2$ and $\operatorname{rank}(M)=3$ when $\varepsilon=1/2$.

Comment: Hello user1551, thank you for answering ! Well I believe that´s possible since C is related to S1 and S2 ! But I find a good idea to turn the rank of M dependent of the C rank too(M is a covariance matrix)! all the best GoodSpirit

Comment: @GoodSpirit Unless $C,S_1,S_2$ have some very special relationships, including the rank of $C$ into consideration will not help. See my new edit.

Comment: Hi user1551, you are right,maybe the rank should be expressed as function of the submatrices only. The paper "Equalities and inequalities for inertias of Hermitian matrices with applications" proves that it is possible for a more general case. I'll change the initial problem formulation... many thanks GoodSpirit